# Marionette - error on call of Layout extend Marionette.LayoutView.extend

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In my app, I am using Marionette the extension of Backbone. I installed backbone + marionette with using NPM and Browserify.  I am getting as a first error as :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined**

driver.js

```
require('./setup.js');

var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');


var TodoList = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  el: '#app-hook',
  template: require('./app/templates/layout.html')
});

var todo = new TodoList({
  model: new Backbone.Model({
    items: [
      {assignee: 'Scott', text: 'Write a book about Marionette'},
      {assignee: 'Andrew', text: 'Do some coding'}
    ]
  })
});

todo.render();
```

compile project with command **browserify driver.js -t node-underscorify -o static/app.js** Whithout errors.

Please any help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm the version of Marionette you are using?  If it's version 3 `LayoutView` was removed and you should use `View` instead:

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
  el: '#app-hook',
  template: require('./app/templates/layout.html')
});
```

You can read about more changes in their [upgrade guide](http://marionettejs.com/docs/master/upgrade.html).